# Q: How to query contacts information via API without using my own user&password in the scripts

Tags: api

I am looking to write several scripts to query contacts and filter them by some custom fields and pipe the result to another system.

What I was able to achieve by now is using `Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP` and SOAP to achieve this, but that required me to use my own user&password in the scripts.

Is there a way to secure this? like having a uniqe token which have only the permission to connect and query this specific fields ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The easiest way may be to create an [apex web service](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts)

Comment: way more complicated than I was hoping for.